# Can't get flask blueprint to work

Tags: flask

I'm learning Blueprints in Flask and wrote the following short script to test how urls can be served from the blueprint:

```python
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
bp = Blueprint('bp', __name__)

app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix='/bp')

@bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bp_home():
    return("And a new blueprint is born!")

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def app_home():
    return("App home is here!")

app.run()
```

I was expecting that while `http://localhost:5000` should give me the string "App home is here!", `http://localhost:5000/bp` should return "And a new blueprint is born!". Unfortunately, only the former works; the latter one gives me a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `app.register_blueprint` *after* you've defined the routes for the blueprint.

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
bp = Blueprint('bp', __name__)


@bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bp_home():
    return("And a new blueprint is born!")

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def app_home():
    return("App home is here!")

app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix='/bp')

app.run()
```